# Docker. Create volume in volume

Tags: laravel, selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have to create volume in volume in Docker.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - selenium_downloads:/var/www/storage/selenium-downloads
        links:
            - selenium

    selenium:
        container_name: selenium
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/selenium.docker
        volumes:
          - selenium_downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads


volumes:
    selenium_downloads:
```

As you can see, I'm sharing my project code with a volume. And inside I want to share selenium downloads between `app`/`selenium` containers.

I do not know why, but my setup is not working.

Is it possible to do that? If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your selenium container is downloading the selenium packages, so the sequence of container creation should be, 1. Selenium, 2.App.

Use 
`services:`

`app:`

`image: dockersamples/example`

`depends_on: - selenium`

Also once go inside the container by `docker exec -ti container-id` to see if files are there in the directory you mapped with volume.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on your answer?

What's wrong with the order?

I have such a flow `selenium` downloads file -> `app` processes file -> I see results on my local machine.

Comment: So to maintain the order that selenium downloads files first and then its later used by app, you would need to specify under app service that it depends_on selenium so that compose will create the selenium container first and then it will create app container.

Comment: But it does it. `links` acts in the same way. I have no errors during build/setup.